# Matching two almost similar string (python)

Tags: python, regex

In a file I can have either of the following two string formats:

```
::WORD1::WORD2= ANYTHING
::WORD3::WORD4::WORD5= ANYTHING2
```

This is the regex I came up with:

```
::(\w+)(?:::(\w+))?::(\w+)=(.*)

regex.findall(..)

[(u'WORD1', u'', u'WORD2', u' ANYTHING'),
 (u'WORD3', u'WORD4', u'WORD5', u' ANYTHING2')]
```

My first question is, why do I get this empty `u''` when matching the first string ?

My second question is, is there an easier way to write this regex? the two strings are very similar, except that sometimes i have this extra `::WORD5`

My last question is: most of the time I have only word between the `::` so that's why `\w+` is enough, but sometime I can get stuff like `2-WORD2` or `3-2-WORD2` etc.. there is this `-` that appears. How can I add it into the `\w+` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer of thg435 you can just split to the "=" and then do exactly the same somethign like

```
left,right = a.split('=', 1)
answer = left.split('::')[1:] + [right]
```

Answer (score 1):

Captured groups are always included in `re.findall` results, even if they don't match anything. That's why you get an empty string. If you just want to get what's between the delimiters, try `split` instead of `findall`:

```
a = '::WORD1::WORD2= ANYTHING'
b = '::WORD3::WORD4::WORD5= ANYTHING2'

print re.split(r'::|= ', a)[1:] # ['WORD1', 'WORD2', 'ANYTHING']
print re.split(r'::|= ', b)[1:] # ['WORD3', 'WORD4', 'WORD5', 'ANYTHING2']
```

In response to the comments, if "ANYTHING" could be well, anything, it's easier to use string functions rather than regexps:

```
x, y = a.split('= ', 1)
results = x.split('::')[1:] + [y]
```

Comment: This solution looks simple, but is possibly a bit too simple, since the distinction between WORDx and ANYTHING is not possible, and ANYTHING may contain any character without further split occurring.

Comment: I think that won't work for what Johny19 needs. When he says "ANYTHING" it is that it probably can get either "::" or "=" inside the "ANYTHING" so that will break down into a list as well.. Otherwise that would be an elegant solution

Comment: Yes exactly (Alexis and guidot). But thanks anyway thg435 that was quit smart !

Answer (score 1):

for last question:

```
[\w\-]+
```

explain:

> ***`\w`***
>   Matches any word character.

Answer (score 0):

For you last question you can do something like (that accept letters, numbers and "-")

```
[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+
```

Comment: Or do what Ria says, it is even better :p